# Modify column of dates using R data.table package

Tags: r, date, data.table

I have a data file that currently has over 1.7 million rows and grows weekly.  I'm trying to use R to create a script that summarizes quality based on our performance over time (product age plays heavily into this) as well as trends what our problems are in the field.  Originally I thought about using `dplyr` and `read.csv()` versus using `data.table` and `fread()`.  The speed difference is what is driving me toward `data.table`, but I'm struggling with the syntax.

Data was stored originally in CSV file using date codes such as 201501 (January 2015) or 20150127 (January 27, 2015).  I am trying to convert these dates to standard dates that I can calculate product age (Manufacture date to date of service call).  I want to change 201601 to 2016-01-31.

I tried the following using the `zoo` package - I expected a date but I got the original 6-digit code back.  My laptop was running quite a while on this.

```
DT <- DT[, Mfrdate:=as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(MfrDate), "%Y%m"), frac = 1)]
```

I searched Google and the data.table cheat sheet and thought I must being approaching this wrong - the set() appears to be the correct way to do this.  I then tried the following:

```
set(DT,i = .N , j = "MfrDate", value = as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(DT[,2]), "%Y%m"), frac = 1)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in set(DT, i = .N, j = "MfrDate", value = as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(DT[,  : 
  i[1] is 1821628 which is out of range [1,nrow=1761094].
```

I thought the i = .N was incorrect, so, I took it out and mistakenly ran the command before changing it to something else.  It ran without warnings or errors, but it changed all of my column to NA's.  I'm missing something.

Help is appreciated.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RevoUtilsMath_3.2.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.2.3
```

Comment: Have you tried converting your date "format" to a standard R date format with a build function, so you can convert it using as.Date() or any other way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first syntax works as expected with this example:

```
require(data.table)
require(zoo)
require(stringr)
DT <- data.table(r=c(1,2,3), MfrDate=c(200101, 20010228, 200103))
DT <- DT[str_length(MfrDate)==6, Mfrdate:=as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(MfrDate), "%Y%m"), frac = 1)]
DT <- DT[str_length(MfrDate)==8, Mfrdate:=as.Date(as.yearmon(as.character(MfrDate), "%Y%m%d"), frac = 1)]
head(DT)

   r  MfrDate    Mfrdate
1: 1   200101 2001-01-31
2: 2 20010228 2001-02-28
3: 3   200103 2001-03-31
```

So the reported error is probably linked to some incorrect data in your dataset

Comment: This will not work with the OP's data. They mention that some dates have the day also, and some just have month and year. Your method will ignore the day portion and assign the last day of the month to all values.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @PierreLafortune : I edited to include YYYYMMDD as well as YYYYMM

Comment: Thank you very much folks!  @HubertL, you are correct... I had "cleaned" the data to eliminate dates with the wrong number of characters, but I didn't clean the data to eliminate things like 199900 (month 00 of 1999) or 760510 (month 10 of the year 7605.  I need to take a step back and continue to tidy my data.  Thank you.

Comment: Works well, now!  Thanks, all!

Comment: how to change 2001-01-31 to 2001-01-01 and 2001-03-31 to 2001-03-01 with as.yermon

Thank you in advance

Mathieu

Comment: Hi @MathieuLenormand! Please post a new question. You can comment here with the link so I'll be notified